# Android : Soft Keyboard covering edit text up (adjustresize or adjustpan doesnt work)

Tags: android

Android Developers...

I am new in developing android application. Thus, i really ask for a slow or details explanation about the problem:

1. As the title, the soft keyboard always covering up the edit text. Non of the adjustresize or adjustpan works.
2. I already search this problem, some people say to make the application not fullscreen. I already make my own simple theme which only consist: 
   false
   still/ it doesnt work. Thus, how to disable full screen correctly?
3. Some people say to use scrollview. Is it the only answer for it? because i would rather to use relative or linear layout.
4. is there any simple answer to make the soft keyboard behaves well?

Thank you so much for your help :D

Ps:

1. android:minSdkVersion="7"
2. I am targetting for 2.1
3. There is no such implicit theme on my manifest that state the theme is fullscreen mode.
4. The awkward is: my login activity, the edittext is sliding up to make a room for the soft keyboard. but whenever this activity is called again, the sliding up for edittext does not working.

this is my activity xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/bgcolor"
    android:orientation="vertical" >    

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/textTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Transfer Tanpa Berita" />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="30dp"
        android:text="No Rekening Tujuan: " />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/transferNoRek"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:inputType="number" 
        android:maxLength="20">
    </EditText>
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="30dp"
        android:text="Jumlah: " />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/transferJumlah"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:inputType="number" 
        android:maxLength="20">
    </EditText>
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="30dp"
        android:text="No HP Tujuan: " />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/transferNoHP"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:inputType="number" 
        android:maxLength="15">
    </EditText>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/transferButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Kirim" 
        android:onClick="validatePin">
    </Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally find the answer to my own problem.

I set android:windowSoftInputMode int the Tab Activity not the actual activity. In my opinion, its because the Tab activity is the one who calls other activities.

Thanks.

Comment: can you tell me which android:windowSoftInputMode do you set for solved issues ?