# Android avoid keyboard covering Edit Text programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

I have coded below general, everytime usable functions to display and dismiss keyboard:

|==| Display and Dismiss keyboard Programmatically:

```
InputMethodManager iptKeybodMgrVar;

void keybodDspFnc(EditText txtEdtVyuVar)
{
    txtEdtVyuVar.requestFocus();
    if (iptKeybodMgrVar == null)
    {
        iptKeybodMgrVar = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    }
    iptKeybodMgrVar.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
}

void keybodDsmFnc(EditText txtEdtVyuVar)
{
    iptKeybodMgrVar.hideSoftInputFromWindow(txtEdtVyuVar.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

But problem is, When the Edit Text is below Keyboard, The activity does not shift upwards. It shifts only when a user starts typing.

So how do I make it shift upwards as soon as keyboard appears?

I went thru all links below and nothing helped me:

[Android: How do I prevent the soft keyboard from pushing my view up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207880/android-how-do-i-prevent-the-soft-keyboard-from-pushing-my-view-up)

[adjustPan not preventing keyboard from covering EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558810/adjustpan-not-preventing-keyboard-from-covering-edittext)

[Android : Soft Keyboard covering edit text up (adjustresize or adjustpan doesnt work)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8642303/android-soft-keyboard-covering-edit-text-up-adjustresize-or-adjustpan-doesnt)

https://readyandroid.wordpress.com/android-soft-keyboard-covers-edittext-field-overscroll-to-soft-keyboard/

I tried and didn't work:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateAlwaysHidden" 

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateAlwaysHidden" 

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustPan"
```

Also tried this codes:

(So, Not duplicate of :) [Move layouts up when soft keyboard is shown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964789/move-layouts-up-when-soft-keyboard-is-shown)

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);

getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);

//This Code brings up the keyboard at starting of the activity and pushes all Edit Text up. So not useful 
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE|
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

I can add ScrollView but it seems like just workaround and doesn't seem a solution.

Feel there should be a solution programmatically like setting something InputMethodManager.

Comment: can you put your xml code ?

Comment: I am adding Relative Layout and add edit text programmatically and dynamicaly. So no XML.

Comment: the entire xml ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move layouts up when soft keyboard is shown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964789/move-layouts-up-when-soft-keyboard-is-shown)

Comment: @MehulKanzariya : I tried all in your link and dint help me. I edit my question accordingly.

Comment: Do you use full screen mode into your activity?

Comment: Dmitriy.. No I am not using full screen mode

Comment: I think you have a draggable view with edit text inside it and you are expecting the draggable view to be visible in the screen (above the keyboard) when the keyboard is opened. Did I get your requirement?

Comment: @KedarTendolkar : Yes exactly same. Entire Relative Layout shud move up so the Edit Text also moves above with the relative layout. This movement happens automatically when the user starts typing but shud happen as soon as keyboard comes up.

Comment: did you found any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your **EditText** inside **LinearLayout**, then wrap it with **ScrollView**. It little bit hard if you did via code, so my suggestion is change your xml layout.

Comment: As I hav mentioned in Question, ScrollView seems to be a workaround but not a soltion for the issue. Adding scrollview is causing other layout problems. My Edit Text are inside relative layout and can be moved around the screen.

Answer (score 0):

**Your root layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/root"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!--extra views-->


    <!--add below layout programmatically-->
    <!--<include layout="@layout/layout_dynamic"/>-->


    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Dynamic layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/dynamicLinearLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**add view dynamically** (no need to specify behaviour)

```
private void addEditText(){
    RelativeLayout mRootLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.root);

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mActivity);
    View newView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_dynamic,mRootLayout);
    EditText editText = (EditText) newView.findViewById(R.id.editText);

    mRootLayout.addView(newView);


}
```

**Manifest file**

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
```

Comment: Your code didn't help me. Reason 1) ScrollView can host only on subview. 2) Edit text shud be inside relative layout since it can be movable.